# Confused why my program won't define this

Tags: procedural-programming

I legitimately think the problem is that pwgenerator isn't getting defined, but im' not sure why. Any ideas? On mine, when i run this to define it, pwgenerator stays blue for some reason, and it didn't before.

```
  pwgen[length_Integer:5, num_Integer:1, similars_Boolean:1] := 
 pwgenerator[length, num, similars] = 
  Module[{list, valid, validchars, similar, k, j, password, pwlist, 
    lcase, ucase, digits, spec, s}, lcase = Alphabet[];
   ucase = Capitalize[lcase];
   digits = Range[0, 9];
   spec = StringPartition["!:#$%\'()*+,-./:;>=<?@{}[]^_|~", 1];
   validchars = Flatten[Union[lcase, ucase, digits, spec]];
   similar = StringPartition["Il10O5S2Z", 1];
   list = {};
   (* Evleything above here sets up valid keys to use for password generation *)
   Table[valid = 0;
    While[valid == 0,
     For[j = 0; k = {};, j < length, j++, 
      AppendTo[k, RandomInteger[{1, Length[validchars]}]]]; (* FOR creates 
random integer values between 1 and Length[validchars] *)
     k = Flatten[k];
     password = validchars[[k]]; (* take those elements out, and check if 
there are any of the similar in the password.*)
(* If there is, and similars is 0, restart and reselect the password. If 
there isn't, and similars is 1, we do the same, otherwise we accept the 
password and Return it *)
     Which[(Length[Intersection[password, similar]] >= 1 && similars == 0 ), 
      valid = 0;, (Length[Intersection[password, similar]] == 0 && 
        similars == 1), 
      valid = 0;, (Length[Intersection[password, similar]] == 0 && 
        similars == 0 ), valid = 1; 
      Return[password], (Length[Intersection[password, similar]] >= 1 && 
        similars == 1), valid = 1; Return[password]];
     ], {num}];


   ]
```

Comment: It's hard to debug if I don't know what everything is supposed to be doing. When I run this, it just runs and doesn't return anything, how long should it take? You have a `While` loop there, how often do you expect it to run before returning? Can you put in `Print` or `Echo` statements to see if they are changing as you expect them to?

Comment: But I do see code like this, `Intersection[password, similar] >= 1` that is problematic, since `Intersection` is going to return a list, which isn't comparable to an integer. I think you want to use `Length` there

Comment: @JasonB. Yes you are right about that. I’ll add details and comments momentarily so everything is clearer

Comment: Do the comments i added help @JasonB? It should only take a couple seconds to run. Mine just spits back out what i  input; ie pwgen[5,1,1] outputs pwgen[5,1,1]. I

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the following has the same functionality:

```
ClearAll[pwgen];
pwgen[length_Integer: 5, num_Integer: 1, similarsallowedQ_: True] := 
 pwgenerator[length, num, similarsallowedQ] = 
  Module[{notvalid, validchars, similar, password},
   validchars = Union[
     Alphabet[],
     Capitalize[Alphabet[]],
     IntegerString[Range[0, 9]],
     StringPartition["!:#$%\'()*+,-./:;>=<?@{}[]^_|~", 1]
     ];
   If[Not[similarsallowedQ],
    validchars = Complement[validchars, StringPartition["Il10O5S2Z", 1]];
    ];
   RandomChoice[validchars, {num, length}]
   ]
```

There were numerous issues with your original code:

There is no built-in head `Boolean` in Mathematica.

Instead of doing `AppendTo[k, RandomInteger[{1, Length[validchars]}]]]` in a `For` loop, you can just do `RandomInteger[{1, Length[validchars]}, length]`. `Append` has to copy the whole list, so it makes the code needlessly slow to execute.

Instead of `password = validchars[[k]];` you can have `password = RandomChoice[validchars, length]` right from the beginning.

Instead of first generating passwords and throwing out the invalid ones, you can attempt to generate valid passwords at the first place by setting `validchars = Complement[validchars,similar]`. That saves you the whole `While` loop. However, I admit that this may be not so easy for more complicated rules for validity.

Using `Return` is almost always wrong in Mathematica. Moreover, you compute the same intersections multiple times. Your `Table` could look like this.

```
Table[
  notvalid = True;
  While[notvalid,
   password = RandomChoice[validchars, length];
   n = Length[Intersection[password, similar]];
   Which[
    (n >= 1 && ! similarsallowed), notvalid = True,
    (n == 0 && similarsallowed), notvalid = True,
    (n == 0 && ! similarsallowed), notvalid = False,
    (n >= 1 && similarsallowed), notvalid = False
    ];
   ];
  password,
  {num}
  ];
```

Moreover, my understanding is that if similars are allow but a generated password contains no similars then it should still be valid, but that is your decision.

Comment: It was more just to see if I could get a function working that had optional arguments, not actually making a legitimate password generator. I also like the way you made it much more concise. Thanks. The reason mine wasn’t defining was due to the Boolean head.